# How to preserve old content when setting content of ContentPane

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo, contentpane

Apparently Dojo does some clean-up when setting the `content` property of a ContentPane. For example: if I set `content` to widget A, then set `content` to widget B, widget A's `domNode` is null'ed out. I'd like to set `content` back to widget A, but the ContentPane is filled with "undefined" because widget A's `domNode` was cleaned up.

**Any way to prevent the ContentPane's old content from being cleaned up? Or is there a method to swap different widgets in a ContentPane without using `setContent()` or `set('content', ...)`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `StackContainer` for the content and then add each widget to the stack.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/layout/StackContainer.html